# How to start a singleton task in an ada package

Tags: package, task, ada

I am doing some Ada this Sunday ..
;-)

I have write a small Log package:

log.ads:

```
package Log is
    procedure log (text: String);
end Log;
```

log.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body Log is

    procedure log (text: String) is
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put (text);
    end log;

end Log;
```

I can use it like this:
test.adb:

```
with Log;

procedure Test is
begin
    Log.log ("bla bla");
end Test;
```

Now, I would like to "improve" this package. I would like the log procedure to "push" the text to a task. It is the task that does the "Ada.Text_IO.Put (text)".
The task can be:

```
task Logger_Task is
    entry log (text : String);
end Logger_Task;

task body Logger_Task is
begin
    loop
        accept log (text: String) do
            Ada.Text_IO.Put (text);
        end log;
    end loop;
end Logger_Task;
```

I would like that the Log clients are not aware of this task, so it should be hidden somewhere into the Log package.
I do not know how and where to instantiate the task ...

This task must also remain active throughout the duration of the application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You already instantiated it.

```
task Logger_Task is
    entry log (text : String);
end Logger_Task;
```

is the same as creating an instance of an anonymous `task type`:

```
task type Anonymous is
    entry log (text : String);
end Anonymous;
Logger_Task : Anonymous;
```

Comment: Ha ok ! Thanks ! But now, the main procedure is blocked (Infinite loop in the task). How the task can be terminated at the end of the program ?

Comment: You could periodically poll the status of the environment task:
`exit when not Ada.Task_Identification.Is_Callable
            (Ada.Task_Identification.Environment_Task);`

Comment: Be aware though, that whatever happens inside the `accept` will block the calling task, so calling `Ada.Text_IO.Put` in a rendezvous like that, will not _"push" the text to a task_ in the way you want

Comment: Ok. My purpose was to not block the calling task. So how can I do ?

Comment: @egilhh, I think this is one case where a `terminate` alternative in the `select` would work. Also, I think we’re going to need to use unbounded strings so as to copy the `text` parameter value out of the `accept`.

Answer (score 5):

If you define the task in the body of the package, you can keep the `procedure log` interface:

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package body Log is

   task Logger_Task is
      entry log (text : String);
   end Logger_Task;

   task body Logger_Task is
      Cache: Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept log (text: String) do
               Cache := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String (text);
            end log;
            Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO.Put (Cache);
         or
            terminate;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Logger_Task;

   procedure log (text: String) is
   begin
      Logger_Task.log (text);
   end log;
end Log;
```

`select … or terminate;` is vital to end the task when the main task ends (this alternative will only be taken when the main task has reached its end).

`Cache` is also important because it allows the calling task to continue after the `text` parameter has been received by the `accept` block. Directly calling `Put` in the accept block will make the calling task wait for it to finish, since it only continues after the `accept` block has been left.

Comment: Cool ! Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

A method using rendezvous was shown by another user, but if the means of handling that message could block, then even if you do that outside the accept statement, the caller could still potentially block waiting on the logger task to get back around to the accept statement.  Text_IO should not be much of a problem, but for other types of outputs that potentially could block longer, consider an alternative:

Use an [unbounded synchronized queue](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-28.html) paired with a standalone task that monitors the queue and retrieves messages from it as they are added and it has the time.  Even though it is an entry, the Enqueue operation will not block the calling task. This way, if the output method for your logger ends up blocking for relatively long periods of time occasionally, your other tasks will just pop messages on a queue and move on and the monitoring task will eventually output them when it catches up.

**logging.ads**

```ada
package Logging is

   procedure Put_Line(Message : String);

end Logging;
```

**logging.adb**

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces;
with Ada.Containers.Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Task_Identification; use Ada.Task_Identification;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

package body Logging is

   -- Create the queue
   package Interfaces is new Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces(Unbounded_String);
   package Queues is new Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues(Interfaces);
   Messages : Queues.Queue;

   -- This task will monitor the queue until the program ends
   task Logger;

   task body Logger is
      Message : Unbounded_String := Null_Unbounded_String;
   begin

      -- Stop looping once both main ends and there are no messages left
      -- The Environment_Task refers to the task that runs Main
      while Is_Callable(Environment_Task) or Messages.Current_Use > 0 loop

         -- Check the queue for a message but time out if not.  We
         -- need the timeout because Dequeue can block if the queue 
         -- is empty.
         select
            Messages.Dequeue(Message);
            Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO.Put_Line(Message);
         or
            -- Pick a timeout that makes sense.  Longer timeouts 
            -- give better CPU usage during idle times, but also means
            -- the program might not end immediately. 10ms or 1 second
            -- might be fine for general use
            delay 1.0;
         end select;

      end loop;

      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Main task closed, closing Logger");

   end Logger;

   procedure Put_Line(Message : String) is 
   begin
      Messages.Enqueue(To_Unbounded_String(Message));
   end Put_Line;

end Logging;
```

Comment: While you are correct that having a queue will lead to less blocking, your proposed solution could be instead implemented with a protected type with guarded entries, which would enable you to still employ `select … or terminate` instead of running a lot of empty loops.

Comment: @flyx I tried that but it would just give a compiler error on the line with terminate saying "statement expected" and "only allowed alternative in timed entry call is delay".  As far as I understand, the Dequeue operation is a guarded entry (it blocks until there is something  in the queue).  That was with:   loop select Messages.Dequeue(Message); Put_Line(Message); or terminate; end select; end loop;  Do you have an example?

Comment: @flyx nevermind, "or delay" worked even though or terminate didn't.  I'll update

Comment: You are right, `terminate` is indeed not possible in that case. However I do think that there has to be a solution that does not include an active delay loop.

Comment: The only one I could come up with involved trading out the auto termination in favor of having the main function strobe the logger to shut it down manually.  At this point it feels like I am getting into premature optimization territory as occasionally waking up and going right back to sleep once a second is in the noise of a task that is doing something like disk IO or even console IO?  Automatic termination is worth that trade off.  If you come up with a way to auto terminate while also cutting out the active delay loop, let me know.   I couldn't figure out a way to keep both.